# Mongoose request for id field returns id and _id

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Mongoose schema I have an `id` field which has a unique ID for each document. This runs off the same system used by the default `_id` field like so:

```
var JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type:String, required:true, unique:true, index:true, default:mongoose.Types.ObjectId },
  title: { type: String },
  brief: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Job", JobSchema);
```

Now, if I query the schema to get id and title I'd do it like this:

```
Job.find().select("id title").exec(function(err, jobs) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send(jobs);
});
```

However, I've found this returns `id` and `title` as expected, but it also return the default `_id` field. Why is that and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the `find()` function you can pass two parameters (criteria and projection). Projection are the fields that you want (or not). In your case you can change your code to

```
Job.find({}, {_id:0, id: 1, title: 1}, function(err, jobs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(jobs);
});
```

and it should do it.

Comment: Amazing, I never knew you could do that! Thanks so much

Comment: @Coop You can also just add `-_id` to the existing `select` call, so that it's `Job.find().select("-_id id title")`

Comment: When I try to do this `{_id:0, id: 1}` the projection correctly includes the "id" field only, but it's set to null? When I switch change it to `{_id:1, id: 1}` the "id" property displays the correct value, but of course I didn't want the _id field in the projection? Strange behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option to prevent the id on schema level. 
For me this worked perfectly fine.

```
new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });
```

[Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id)

Comment: This works better for me especially when using virtuals and populate